# Using AutoMapper to map from XElement to a strongly typed class?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Can I use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to map from data in an XElement to my own type ? How ?

Comment: http://stanbashtavenko.com/using-automapper-for-xelements/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can but in any case you will end up writing a function that does the conversion from the non strongly typed `XElement` to your strongly typed class, so `AutoMapper` wouldn't bring much value here. You could use `ConvertUsing` or write a custom `ITypeConverter`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ValueInjecter for this, look at this link, it's something similar:

http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=218448